Set openvpn username and password via env-variable
I have a rather long password that I want to automate using a secret manager, I don't want to store it in plaintext.
Judging from this answer, I can achieve this using env-variables, which is great.
A quick check using sudo openvpn --config ~/Documents/config.ovpn --auth-user-pass test.txt works, also great! I need sudo, otherwise openvpn doesn't work.
But I can't get the command right, I am probably making some trivial mistake.
I tried:
sudo openvpn --config ~/Documents/config.ovpn --auth-user-pass <(echo -e $VPN_USER"\n"$VPN_PASS)

but that results in:
2024-04-13 20:11:43 WARNING: cannot stat file '/proc/self/fd/14': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Options error: --auth-user-pass fails with '/proc/self/fd/14': No such file or directory (errno=2)

which I think is due to my sudo usage. So I tried something else (I am not exactly a bash-pro):
cat <(echo -e $VPN_USER"\n"$VPN_PASS) | sudo /usr/sbin/openvpn --config ~/Documents/config.ovpn --auth-user-pass 

but that results in:
Password entry required for 'Enter Auth Username:' (PID 191957).
Please enter password with the systemd-tty-ask-password-agent tool.

It's probably an easy question.

Have you considered using sudo to run not just openvpn itself but your wrapper? It's the privilege boundary that breaks process substitution; if both parts are on the same side of that boundary there's no issue.

Also, while this isn't strictly your problem, echo -e "$foo\n$bar" has unintended consequences. printf '%s\n' "$foo" "$bar" is safer -- it doesn't treat the contents of your variables as format strings themselves, and it's compatible with shells and shell configurations that don't honor the -e argument to echo as anything other than a string to print on output (which is what a strict reading of POSIX requires, so even in bash that behavior can be disabled).

Mind, there are other options as well -- if you look at the POSIX equivalents to <() using mkfifo to create a named pipe, those'll work in cases where the /dev/fd optimization doesn't.

Thanks! I used a 1password to manage the password and it only knows it in the non-root setting. Not sure whether I am meant to use it as root. I got something working in the answer, but I am not sure why? I suspect it's the boundary between root and non-root but I am not sure why it happens and why my weird command works.

One approach to fixing this would be to consider the question a duplicate of using bash process substitution for a sudo command -- but note that the proper fix requires /etc/sudoers to be configured a particular way.

sudo by default closes all file descriptors other than stdin, stdout and stderr -- so it deliberately invalidates /dev/fd references.
You can avoid this problem by using a named FIFO -- just like bash does for >(...) and <(...) when running on operating systems that don't support /dev/fd.
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tempdir=$(mktemp -t -d authsock.d.XXXXXX) || exit
trap 'rm -rf "$tempdir"; [[ $write_pid ]] && kill "$write_pid"' EXIT

mkfifo "$tempdir/sock" || exit
printf '%s\n' "$VPN_USER" "$VPN_PASS" >"$tempdir/sock" & write_pid=$!

sudo openvpn \
  --config /home/leander/Documents/Informatics-EdLAN-Forum.ovpn \
  --auth-user-pass "$tempdir/sock"


this works! thanks! It's also quite complex, more than I thought!
